# What's stack's default template?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When you don't specify the template, what is the default?

i.e. when running the command `stack new foo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As seen in the [source code](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/aac2c81dd020e399b49894c566075a495240baaf/src/Stack/New.hs#L355), it's the template named `new-template`.

It's located here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates/blob/master/new-template.hsfiles

In fact, when you try out your command - it says so:

```
sibi { ~ }-> stack new foo
Downloading template "new-template" to create project "foo" in foo/ ...
```